# Не регистрирует нового пользователя, Django 3

Tags: python, html, sql, django, form

Мучаюсь с регистрацией нового пользователя. Django 3.2.13, Python 3.10
После заполнения форм при удачной записи в таблицу данных, должно перенести на страницу логования, но этого не происходит, понятия не имею в чем причина. Помогите.

`forms.py`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm
from django import forms

from users.models import User (только додал поле image для AbstractUser)
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control py-4', 'placeholder': 'Enter your first name'
    }))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control py-4', 'placeholder': 'Enter your last name'
    }))
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control py-4', 'placeholder': 'Enter username'
    }))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control py-4', 'placeholder': 'Enter your email address'
    }))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

`registrations.html`:

```html
<form action="{% url    'users:registration' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.first_name.id_for_label }}">First name</label>
                {{ form.first_name }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.last_name.id_for_label }}">Last name</label>
                {{ form.last_name }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}">Username</label>
            {{ form.username }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}">Email address</label>
            {{ form.email }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.password1.id_for_label }}">Password</label>
                {{ form.password1 }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.password2.id_for_label }}">Repeat the password</label>
                {{ form.password2 }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-4 mb-0">
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Create a account">
    </div>
</form>
```

`views.py`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import auth, messages
from django.urls import reverse

from users.forms import UserLoginForm, UserRegistrationForm

def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created. You can log in now!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:login'))
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'users/registration.html', context)
```

Comment: Попробуйте return redirect ('login')